# Replace values in array of object with values from another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pass-by-reference

This should be a small task, but could not figure it out.
I've an array of objects named 'A'

```
A = [{x:a,y:10},{x:b,y:5},{x:c,y:50}]
```

and an array named 'B'

```
B = ['2022-06-15','2022-06-16','2022-06-17']
```

Need to replace the value of x in A with the values of B

Expected output C

```
C = [{x:'2022-06-15',y:10},{x:'2022-06-16',y:5},{x:'2022-06-17',y:50}]
```

I'm using a for loop but it changes the original array 'A' (since JS arrays are pass-by-reference)

```
const D = A; // or D = [...A]

for (let i = 0; i < D.length; i++) {
        D[i].x = B[i];
}
console.log(A);
console.log(D);
```

Comment: `const D = [...A]` to shallow copy the array. There is also `const D = A.slice();`, and many more methods to shallow copy arrays.

Comment: @kelly He needs to deep-copy it.

Comment: Oh, yeah I got `D[i].x` and `B[i]` switched around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make `D` a copy of `A`. Loop over `A` and make copies of each object with the `x` property replaced.

```
const D = A.map((el, i) => ({...el, x: B[i]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with .map() method

```
    const A = [{
      x: 'a',
      y: 10
    }, {
      x: 'b',
      y: 5
    }, {
      x: 'c',
      y: 50
    }];

const B = ['2022-06-15', '2022-06-16', '2022-06-17'];
```

`x` represents each element inside your `A` array and `i` the `index`, that you will use to loop thru your second array `B`

```
const C = A.map((x, i) => ({
  x: B[i],
  y: x.y
}));

console.log(C);
```